# How to filter String array in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

By using **objective C** I have filter year array by using **NSPredicate**,

Below is code.

```
  yearArray = [yearArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate
  predicateWithFormat:@"SELF != ''"]];
```

As per above code it's working fine in objective c , I have to filter array in **Swift 3**,

**What is Input Year Array  :-**

```
( Year,"","","",JAN,"","","",FEB,"","","",MAR,"","","",APR,"","","",
  MAY,"","","",JUN,"","","",JUL,"","","",AUG,"","","",SEP,"","","",OCT
  ,"","","", NOV,"","","",DEC,"","","","",WIN,"","","",SPR,"","","",SUM
  ,"","","",AUT,"","","","",ANN)
```

**Need filter Output Array**

```
(Year,JAN,FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUN,JUL,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC,WIN,SPR,SUM,AUT,ANN)
```

Please give solution how to filter array in swift.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code:

```
let yearArray: [String] = ... // your array of type [String]

let filteredArray = yearArray.filter {
    !$0.isEmpty
}
```

Look at the picture for output:

[image: Example]

Comment: I have use your code , However it's showing error , Type of expression is ambiguous without more context.

Comment: is your array of type [String] or different?

Comment: NSMutableArray of type string

Comment: If you use Swift, you should use Swift types if there is nothing special about your case. And instead of "NSMutableArray" you can use "var array: [String]".

Comment: If you still use Objective-c type you should still be able to use NSPredicate I think. But as Alexander said, it's better to use swift types when you're writing swift code !

Comment: @AlexanderGoncharov , I have change array type as string it's working perfect .

Comment: That's great :)

Comment: @DamienBannerot , yes bro :)

Answer (score 4):

You can do it by using filter (on an `Array` type) :

```
let filteredArray = yearArray.filter{$0 != ""}
```

It's that simple.

If your array is an `NSMutableArray`, just cast it to `[String]` :

```
if let yearArray = yearArray as? [String] {
    let filteredArray = yearArray.filter{$0 != ""}
    // add your code here
}
```

Comment: `!$0.isEmpty` is preferable to `$0 != ""`. It better communicate intent.